# Which softwere should I use for making covers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, software-recommendation, template

I want to make a cover for my facebook group using a template.
I'm a beginner so that I'm confused about choosing the right software.
Where can I create a cover easily? I have some knowledge of **Photoshop** and **Illustrator**. Which one should I use?
I have some png template downloaded.

Comment: Since you are asking this question, PS and AI might not be ideal for you... I mean you might be able to do it just fine, buuuut... I happened to find this online creator for social media images: https://crello.com — I only tried it just now pretty hastily and it seems good enough. It has a facebook cover preset + free templates. It is a freemium service. If you know how to write an email, you'll probably manage to use that too. You can create a design without making an account, but apparently, you have to create an account before you can download the design _(it has FB and Google singups)_ .

Answer (score 4):

Use whatever works for you and results in the final item you need.

Any choice of software has much to do with a users *preference*. This is especially true if the final product is to merely be a raster image.

Comment: Scott's right: **Photoshop** is a pixel-based design application (with some vector tools mixed in) and **Illustrator** is a vector-based design application (with some pixel-based tools mixed in) and *either* can produce pixel-output designs. **Illustrator's** workflow will largely be based on editable shapes, curves & lines, with strokes and fills, and the results are exported to either vector or raster file types; **Photoshop's** workflow will largely be based on painting & erasing pixels, and the results are exported to many raster file types; choose which *you* ***prefer*** to use!